# User with Negative Age in network profile

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, user-age

I noticed a [network profile of a user](//stackexchange.com/users/6038441/ivsevolod) with the age shown as -972:

> [image]

I dug further to see if there are more such cases but my analysis shows that this is a lone case, though there are a lot of users who have not added their age to their profile. I believe it is a bug in the system that allows the users to enter negative numbers as their age.

I emailed Stack Overflow team about the same and I was suggested to use Meta for 
discussing it further. I would like to know if this is indeed a bug or there is some explanation behind this.

Comment: Users can't manually enter their age, only birth date.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @ShadowWizard

Comment: Hmm.... trying to reproduce in the easy way failed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NyxIN.png

Comment: Probably this filter was added later? Moreover this is the only case of its kind as I checked using the latest StackOverflow user data dump

Comment: Maybe... or maybe that user was really born in 2988 and returned back to the past.... :D

Answer (score 6):

As the reference from [this answer](/a/294638) from the Stack Exchange developer, displaying **Age** from the profile was removed from per-site and network profile.

So hence this problem has been solved.

The actual answer from **Michael Stum** is:

> That was an oversight - we removed Age from Profiles ages ago, but still had the code in. When looking at removing the code completely, I saw that SE.com still uses it, and we removed it there as well now.

Also screenshot for the confirmation:

> [image: Age removed]